# Don't understand "with a cluster"

Tags: phrases

This sentence comes from VOA standard English, "Los Angeles County has seen sixty four cases of typhus so far this year, double a typical number with a cluster among the homeless.". I don't understand what "with a cluster" mean.

Comment: What does your favorite dictionary have to say about the noun *cluster*?

Comment: _With a cluster_ is not a constituent. The constituent is _with a cluster among the homeless_, a phrase composed of the preposition _with_ and the noun phrase object _a cluster among the homeless_. _Cluster_ is a quantifier, meaning 'a cluster of cases of typhus', which appear _among the homeless_, which refers to places where homeless people congregate. It may be VOA standard English, but it's not simple English; quite a lot has been done to the sentences, including leaving out repetitions of the topic.

Comment: I understand what cluster means, I think. Am I the only one who's having trouble understanding this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you may not find the answer in a standard dictionary ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cluster) excepted), because *cluster* has a special meaning in epidemiology:

> A **[disease cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disease_cluster)** is an unusually high incidence of a
>   particular disease or disorder occurring in close proximity in terms
>   of both time and geography.

Comment: Well, yes, but that definition does not actually apply to a cluster among a group of people not defined by time or by geography as the OP's sentence uses it. The idea behind the word is what you would see if you plotted the cases on a map or on a timeline, namely a cluster of points. But there is no map or timeline that shows the homeless and others who suffer from typhus. The usage is lazy thinking combined with the desire to use an impressively technical sounding word.